# How to save socket data in a list in flutter

Tags: flutter, socket.io, riverpod

I am using riverpod in my flutter for desktop in which I have integrated socket io

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:wineasy/services/socket_service.dart';

final providerOfSocket = StreamProvider((ref) async* {
  StreamController stream = StreamController();

  SocketService().socket.on('orderToKitchen', (dataFromServer) {
    stream.add(dataFromServer);

    print(dataFromServer.toString());
  });

  await for (final value in stream.stream) {
    print('stream value => ${value.toString()}');
    yield value;
  }
});
```

here I want to create a list to save dynamic data and feed it to the orders page

I am cannot find a method to do this . please help